# Original reference for the category of elements

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

The category of elements of a presheaf $F:C^{\operatorname{op}} \to \operatorname{Set}$ is the most elementary form of the Grothendieck construction.

I think (but I am unable to find a reference) that the category of elements was studied before Grothendieck's definition for pseudofunctors with values in $\operatorname{Cat}$.

Maybe someone here who is more familiar with older papers in category theory can point to a reference.

Many thanks.

Comment: This question would be better for [HSMSE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Likely to be  SGA4.